# real-time database in firebase, rules

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following problem: I have my app in development, this allows the authenticated user to add data from a crud, in the rules of firebase real-time database, when they are in "true" read and write, they are saved and visualized, but when I try to add the following rule it does not save the data

```
{
// Allow anyone to read data, but only authenticated content owners can
// make changes to their data

  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" for only authenticated users
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
```

It is supposed to be so that the authenticated users can read and write their data, but that the other users can only see the published data. I cannot let users modify the data of others.

Answer (score 0):

Change **some_path** with your refrence **name**

```
{
// Allow anyone to read data, but only authenticated content owners can
// make changes to their data

  "rules": {
    "some_path": {//change this with your ref_name
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" for only authenticated users
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering, I am going to try your recommendation now, a query, what do you mean by reference name? I regret the ignorance. 
Cheers